# find equivalent partitions of an array

Tags: matlab, performance

Suppose to have an algorithm that find a partition of an array `nodes=[1:10]` based on some minimization problem. The output of the algorithm will be an array of indices indicating to which partition a certain nodes is assigned. For example: `part=[1 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2]`.

This algorithm has an issue though. It has a stochastic component and sometimes it can return the same partition but with a different numbering. For example `part2=[2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1]`. In this case `part1` and `part2` are de facto the same partition.

Let's say that I need to run the partitioning algorithm 5 times. The output will be a 5x10 matrix `A`. At the end I need to see how many different partitions the algorithm found. This implies that I need to know how many equivalent partitions are present in `A`.

I wrote an [algorithm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkrdaj1ff81w4z6/distinguish_clusters.m?dl=0) that does this but is **really** slow for large inputs.

Here an example of the input:

```
clusters=[ 1,1,2,2;
           1,1,2,2;
           2,2,1,1;
           1,2,1,2;
           2,1,2,1;
           3,1,2,1;
           2,1,2,1;
           3,1,2,1;
           1,2,1,2];
```

for which I obtain the different partitions, the most frequent partition and the number of times it occurs `m`:

```
true_clusters =

 1     1     2     2
 1     2     1     2
 3     1     2     1


frequest =

 1     2     1     2

m =

 4
```

Does anyone know a fast way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a vectorized version:

Consider rows `[1 2 1 2]` and `[3 1 2 1]`  and `[ 2 1 2 1]` that have the same pattern because in all of them consecutive elements of each vector are different from each other so `diff(clusters,1,2)~=0` for those rows generates the same pattern `[1 1 1]`.
But that is not sufficient to get a correct answer for the algorithm.
Also for each row it is required to have unique elements that appear in it.
so in  `[1 1 2 2]` the unique elements are `[1 2]` and for `[3 1 2 1]` unique elements  are `[1 2 3]`
equally a logical vector can be created that represents if each of `[1 2 3]` are member of a row so for `[1 1 2 2]` logical vector is `[1 1 0]` and for `[3 1 2 1]` is `[1 1 1]` that `accumarray` do the mentioned task.
Concatenating two patterns as `[diff(clusters,1,2)~=0 , ac]` create an array that it's rows represent different partitions. then `unique` function can be applied to extract unique partitions

```
ac=accumarray([ repmat((1:size(clusters,1)).',size(clusters,2),1) clusters(:)],1,[],@any);
[~, v, I]=unique([diff(clusters,1,2)~=0 , ac],'rows');
many= hist(I,I(v));
true_clusters = clusters(v,:);
[m,im] = max(many);
frequest = true_clusters(im,:);
```

Result:

```
many = 3 4 2

true_clusters =

   2   2   1   1
   1   2   1   2
   3   1   2   1

m = 4

frequest = 1 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's fast enough for you:

```
[~,~,c] = unique(clusters','rows','stable'); 

c_unique = unique(c,'rows')
```